# API call via curl, json results in csv or mysql

Tags: php, json, curl

I am very new to PHP, I need to call a api via curl and parse the results into a format that I can import into a data base.  How do I save the results as a csv or push it directly into a database?

Thanks

api call receiving these results

[{"mac":"AC86740410B8","siteId":"1032","name":"main-rtr","desc":"","loc":{"lat":-25.887635,"lng":28.150488,"levelId":0,"source":"manual"},"lrrt":1,"lrne":4}]

this is my code

```
$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen("data.txt", "a+");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://theapi.com/');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER >= array('Content-type: application/json');
$json = ('data.txt');
//json_decode($json, true);
//$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.txt'), true);
var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the decoded results like this:

```
$data = json_decode('[{"mac":"AC86740410B8","siteId":"1032","name":"main-rtr","desc":"","loc":{"lat":-25.887635,"lng":28.150488,"levelId":0,"source":"manual"},"lrrt":1,"lrne":4}]');

$arrayFromResults = array(
  $data[0]->mac,
  $data[0]->loc->lat,
  $data[0]->lrne
);

var_dump( $arrayFromResults ); 

var_dump( $data );
```

( http://codepad.org/kzZ7nhck )

Then easily pass the array to putcsv:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

...or write it into a DB:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.exec.php